# Will a FOR loop like this work in MySql? ...It won't compile for me

Tags: mysql, for-loop

```
create procedure wfhnxtmth
   (in inYear  int,
    in inMonth int)

begin
   FOR week AS 
      SELECT week FROM calendar WHERE month = inMonth
   DO   
      INSERT INTO calname
         (id,year,month,week,monstat,tuestat,wedstat,thustat,fristat,pager)
         SELECT id, inYear, inMonth, week, 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'N'
         FROM name;
   END FOR;
end
```

Comment: This compiles an runs fine in DB2.

Comment: please share the errors so we could get a better insight into the problem

Comment: It doesn't like the FOR syntax that I have entered.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just take sps from one DBMS system to another and expect them to run. You have to rewrite them in the quirky language of the target DBMS.

Comment: Thanks...I realize that I left out the delimiter statements as well.  I don't think MySql has a FOR construct as I have written it...I could probably do the same thing with a WHILE statement.